# d2: Parameter storage class interoperability with functions implemented outside of D

Tags: c, interop, d

#### `const` (and `in`)

Consider there is C function:

```
unsigned int foo(const unsigned int a);
```

`const` will have no effect on generated code, as if code passes compilation with `const`, nothing would break if there weren't `const` — so C compiler uses it at compile time as code contract specifier only.

Is there any effort writing `uint foo(in uint a);` or `uint foo(const uint a);` for calling this function in D? Could this help D compiler generate more efficient code for calling `foo`, or this will have no effect (at least for value type arguments)?

#### `ref` and `out`

There is C function

```
unsigned int bar(unsigned int *a);
```

Am I obliged to use pointer syntax `uint bar(uint* a);` while translating this to D, or can I write `uint bar(ref uint a);` (or `uint bar(out uint a);`, if I know that `a` is only for output, from documentation on `bar`)? Are there additional hidden mechanics under `ref` and `out`, or they are just plain pointers as they seem to? Will D generate "glue code" for initializing `out` parameter to it's default value when call goes out of D scope?

**Update1:** I have written simple code to test how `ref`s and `out`s are handled in arguments — they actually seem to be plain pointers at least for `int`s, but `out` is not reset to initial value when passed — C side can still read it's value and modify it, so it effectively acts like `ref`. I am unsure, if I should expect GC-related issues when I use things in this way.

**Update2:** Using `ref` instead of pointers in function result also works expected way. `const` is still untested, and I don't know how to check for it without need to disassemble my program.

Comment: Simple rule - use C functions the way authors made them.

Comment: It's more subject of understanding of underlying mechanics. Its not always good to just blindly follow instructions without keeping in mind why are these instructions exactly such and not another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` (which is the same as `const scope`) does not exist in C, because `scope` does not exist in C. And `out` and `ref` don't exist in C either. Don't use them with `extern(C)` functions. The compiler should probably give an error if you use them as in the parameters of `extern(C)` functions, but it doesn't surprise me if it doesn't. If it happens to work, you're just "lucky." It may stop working at any time. How `ref` and `out` are implemented are implementation details of the compiler. Generally, you should only ever use modifiers on `extern(C)` functions which actually exist in C. D's compiler isn't going to do any magic to make D stuff work on an `extern(C)` function. It expects an `extern(C)` function to be a *C* function with the capabilities that C has, not D.

The only two exceptions that I'm aware of are `pure` and `nothrow`, since they don't affect calling conventions at all, just whether D will let you call them from certain functions. So, you can mark C functions as `pure` and/or `nothrow`. But you had better be sure that the function is actually pure if you mark it with `pure` (or you could get nasty bugs) - the same goes with `nothrow`. Technically, @safe, @trusted, and @system could be used as well, but C functions really should be left as the default - @system - since they're C functions.

And no, marking a parameter to a C function as `const` is not likely to help any with optimizations. If the parameter is a value type, then the `const` is pointless from the caller's perspective. The argument will be copied regardless. It only matters with reference types. In the case of `extern(C)`, that would be limited to pointers and structs with pointers in them (be it directly or indirectly). There *might* be some optimizations there, but I wouldn't bet on it - especially with dmd, which doesn't generally optimize code as well as gdc and ldc. At best, what the compiler can do is determine that after that call, the variable passed in hasn't changed, which might enable other optimizations within the caller, but it's highly dependent on the caller and the compiler.

What is of greater concern is whether the C parameter is actually `const`. In general, you're fine, but in C, it's legal to cast away `const` and alter a variable, whereas in D, [it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219600/logical-const-in-d). Where this is primarily likely to be a concern is with `immutable` data (string literals being a prime example). You risk a segfault or worse if anything tries to actually mutate the data. In general, that shouldn't be an issue with a C functions parameters which are marked as `const` (though it could be upon occasion), but it definitely means that marking a parameter as `const` when C doesn't is almost certainly a bad idea. If you do that, you need to be sure that the variable's value is never actually altered by the C function. Because if you mark it as `const` and then the C function mutates it, you're going to have bugs.

So, to sum up, I'd say that in general, you should only ever mark `extern(C)` functions with C modifiers, not D-specific ones, and you shouldn't generally mark parameters as `const` unless they're marked that way in C. If you know what the C function is actually `pure`, you can mark it as `pure`. If you know that it's actually `nothrow`, you can mark it with `nothrow`. And if you know that the parameter isn't ever mutated by the C function, then you can mark it as `const`. But you should be very conservative about that, otherwise you *will* cause nasty bugs in your code.

And read these pages if you haven't already:

http://dlang.org/interfaceToC.html
http://dlang.org/htomodule.html

Comment: Brilliant answer, as always. Thank you once again, it's exactly what I was (afraid) to hear :)

Comment: While ref/out may not be defined in the spec for extern(c), I don't see why it can't be. It could allow for being more specific about the intended behavior even though it is just passed as a pointer.

Comment: What would be the point of using `ref` or `out` with `extern(C)`? C doesn't have them. So, it really doesn't make sense to me that it would support them. You're giving a _C_ declaration, not a D one. And D's not generally in the habit of hiding C stuff. It's bad enough to have to mark a C function as `pure` to be able to use it in `pure` functions. I don't see why anyone would expect to be able to use functionality which does not exist in C with `extern(C)` functions. You're _explicitly_ telling it that you're using C linkage rather than D linkage.

Comment: The point is because C functions do take ref and out parameters, while not enforced it does provide intent on the function. As you mentioned const isn't really enforced in C making it also a convention. We put pure and const on C functions because if they do match the descriptions it is the only way to call them from said function type, but it is no different than deciding ref/out will pass a pointer for C functions (which DMD already does).

Comment: Allowing pure is _very_ different, because pure only affects how D will allow you to call the function, whereas ref and out affect the actual parameter types, which get translated into the C signature. I'd strongly argue that they shouldn't be allowed and that the only reason to allow pure and nothrow is to get dmd to shut up without lots of annoying casts. Ideally, they wouldn't be allowed either. Regardless, I opened a bug report on it, so either the compiler will be fixed to complain or the documentation will be updated appropriately: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7854

Answer (score 1):

As C doesn't mangle parameters, thing will be linked with any type qualifier.

It is up to the programmer to ensure that the D type qualifier declared in the extern(C) function prototype actually match what the C function does.

I wouldn't use ref or anything that is a ref with C code as reference doesn't exist in C, so it is likely to not do what you expect (and if it does, it can break at anytime because you are in unspecified world).

EDIT: About const. const in C and const in D are not the same thing (it is transitive in D, it isn't in C). Again it is up the the programmer to determine if the function's parameter can be const qualified according to D semantic or not.

Comment: Okay, it's clear that using `ref` instead of pointers is somewhat hacking - is really this kind of binary compatibility undocumented anywhere? But it's unclear, how does `const` affect whole thing, and if it does at all. Should I specify it for C const arguments or not? Is it safe to specify it always, wherenever it is const or not on C side?

Comment: Edited to better address the const problem.