# Why do I have to cast this?

Tags: d

I've condensed this problem to a small representative sample:

```
import std.stdio;

class Foo
{
    private int f;
}

class State
{
    private Foo foo;
    const Foo getFoo()
    {
        return foo; // This line here.
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto s = new State;
    writeln(s.getFoo());
}
```

I put that code in `test.d`.

```
$ gdmd test.d
test.d:13: Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (this.foo) of type const(Foo) to test.Foo
```

I understand that it's telling me to cast the return value with `cast(test.Foo)foo`, but why? Why does it interpret the member to be of type `const(Foo)` and why does it need me to cast away that `const`? I get the feeling that I'm doing something horribly wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const Foo getFoo()
```

is the same as

```
Foo getFoo() const
```

It makes the invisible `this` parameter `const`. Because `const` is transitive in D, that means that when you try and return a member variable from `this`, it's going to be `const` as well. If `foo` were a value type, then it would just copy it, and then returning a mutable `Foo` wouldn't be a problem, because it wouldn't affect the original. But `Foo` is a class, and therefore is a reference type. So, returning `foo` is returning a reference to the exact same object that `State` holds. No copy is made. And so it *must* be `const` - otherwise you would be violating the constness of the `this` parameter.

And no, casting away `const` is *not* a good solution. As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219600/logical-const-in-d), casting away `const` and then mutating the value is effectively illegal in D. You're violating the type system when you do that. The compiler will let you do it, but if you're taking your life into your own hands when you do. It's especially bad if the underlying object is actually `immutable`, because you can get a segfault in that case. You only cast away `const` if you absolutely have to, and you *never* mutate it unless you *really* know what you're doing.

No, the correct solution is to make the return type `const`:

```
const(Foo) getFoo() const
```

Now, you can return `foo` and use it. If you want a mutable `Foo`, then you either have to not have `getFoo` be `const`, or you have to have `getFoo` return a copy of `foo`. e.g.

```
Foo getFoo() const
{
    //This would be cleaner if you provided a clone/dup function
    //of some kind on Foo.
    auto retval = new Foo;
    retval.f = foo.f;

    return retval;
}
```

The important thing for you to take away from here is that `const` in D is *transitive*. As Walter Bright puts it, "it's turtles all the way down." Once something is `const`, *all* parts of it are `const`, and *don't* cast away `const` to get around it unless you *really* know what you're doing. So, if you want to return a reference type which refers to a member variable from a `const` function, you either need to make the return type `const` or create a copy of it and return that.

Comment: Hooray, I understand much better now.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that what you really want is this:

```
class State
{
    private Foo foo;

    // When `this` is const, return const(Foo).
    // When `this` is immutable, return immutable(Foo).
    // When `this` is mutable, return Foo.
    inout(Foo) getFoo() inout
    {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Which is equivalent of:

```
class State
{
    private Foo foo;

    Foo getFoo()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    const(Foo) getFoo() const
    {
        // `this.foo` is of type const(Foo), as const is transitive.
        return foo;
    }

    immutable(Foo) getFoo() immutable
    {
        // `this.foo` is of type immutable(Foo), as immutable is transitive.
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It interprets the member as `const(Foo)` because your method signature is `const Foo getFoo()`, which implies `foo` will not be mutable.

Remove the `const` and it should be fine.

Comment: The whole point is to have a const accessor function so other people can see but not modify the data. Is it just assuming that because it's the return statement for a function whose return is const? I would have expected it to want me to cast it *to* const, not *from* const in that case.

Comment: Then you should declare the getter as `Foo getFoo() const`. [A similar question here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/806064-i-could-not-get-const-before-function-declaration)

Comment: @Alexander: I get the same issue when I do that, and I can't decipher the language spec well enough to tell what it means.

Comment: @nmichaels: a better way to fix it is actually to probably to say const(Foo) instead of Foo, since D interprets the first const as referring to the method.

Comment: @nmichaels const is transient so (cast(const)s).foo will also be const I think the only way is `const(Foo) getFoo() const`